# How can I get my Pixlee Instagram feed to not disappear on page reload in NextJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, instagram

Here is my code:

```
import { useEffect } from "react";

const InstagramFeed = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    window.PixleeAsyncInit = function () {
      Pixlee.init({ apiKey: "MYAPIKEYISHERE" });
      Pixlee.addSimpleWidget({ widgetId: "37392" });
    };
    const scriptTag = document.createElement("script");
    scriptTag.src =
      "//instafeed.assets.pxlecdn.com/assets/pixlee_widget_1_0_0.js";
    document.body.appendChild(scriptTag);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div id="pixlee_container" className="h-[40rem] overflow-hidden"></div>
  );
};

export default InstagramFeed;
```

I have this component on my homepage and when I initially load up the website and look at the homepage the component shows as it should. But then, once I navigate to a new page and then back to the homepage, the component is no longer there -- it's disappeared.

How can I fix this so that the component continues to show when I come back to the homepage after navigating away from it?

I'm using NextJS.

I figured it was because I put the code into it's own component but it doesn't function any differently when I put it directly on the homepage.

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

Managed to figure it out by reading the documentation of Pixlee. Something I should have done to start with. Would have saved me several hours.

The solution was to initialize Pixlee and call my particular API on my website's first load, and then to use the Pixlee.close(true) function to close the widget anytime I change the page. I integrated that with the NextJS useRouter and solved the problem.

Here's what it looked like, I added this to my layout.js:

```
const router = useRouter();

  useEffect(() => {
    window.PixleeAsyncInit = function () {
      Pixlee.init({ apiKey: "SPECIALAPIKEYGOESHERE" });
    };

    const scriptTag = document.createElement("script");
    scriptTag.src =
      "//instafeed.assets.pxlecdn.com/assets/pixlee_widget_1_0_0.js";
    document.body.appendChild(scriptTag);

    if (router.route === "/") {
      Pixlee.addSimpleWidget({ widgetId: "37392" });
      Pixlee.resizeWidget();
    } else {
      Pixlee.close(true);
      Pixlee.resizeWidget();
    }
  }, []);
```